# problem in permutation question.

Tags: permutations

Find the number of hexadecimal numbers containing at maximum 16 hexadecimal digits with all of the digits 0,1, and A present at least once? Give your answer as a hexadecimal number.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: Please see André Nicolas' answer and define the problem better.  Are leading 0's allowed? As you say number they may not be.  Are shorter numbers than 16 digits allowed?

Comment: even i am not sure about the question. i am contantly getting wrong answers. i have contacted admins but there is no response yet.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is a little different depending on whether we assume that (a) the hex numbers are of full length $16$, with a front padding of $0$'s for small numbers or (b) the length is allowed to be variable, with only $0$ beginning with $0$.

We solve the problem under interpretation (a), and then the ugly modification for interpretation (b).

**Interpretation (a):** Instead of length $16$, it is visually easier to deal with length $n$. There are $16^n$ numbers in total. We must remove the **bad** numbers, in which one at least of $0$, $1$, or $A$ is missing.  This wlll be done by the Method of Inclusion/Exclusion.

There are $15^n$ numbers with $0$ missing, and we have the same number with $1$ missing, and with $A$ missing. But if calculate the sum $15^n+15^n+15^n$, we will count twice the ones in which $0$ **and** $1$ are missing, also $0$ and $A$, also $1$ and $A$. There are $14^n$ of each kind. But if we subtract $3\cdot 14^n$, we will have subtracted one too many times the ones in which $0$, $1$, and $A$ are all missing. There are $13^n$ of these. So the total number of bads is $3\cdot 15^n-3\cdot 14^n+13^n$.

**Interpretation (b):** The length of a good number is $3$ to $16$. For any $k$, there are $(15)(16^{k-1})$ numbers. Again, we count the bads. There are two kinds of bads: (i) bads that start with $1$ or $A$ and (ii) all the others.

To count the bads that start with $1$ or $A$, there are $2$ choices for the first leftmost) digit. For every such choice, say first digit $1$, a bad is something that is missing one of $0$ or $A$ or both. There are $15^{k-1}$ that avoid $0$, $15^{k-1}$ that avoid $A$. Adding double counts the $14^{k-1}$ that avoid both. So the total of type (i) is $(2)(15^{k-1}+15^{k-1}-14^{k-1})$.

To count the bads that start with neither $1$ nor $A$, there are $13$ ways to start. For each of these ways, we count the bads in exactly the same way as we solved the (a) interpretation. We get a total of $(13)(3\cdot 15^{k-1}-3\cdot 14^{k-1}+13^{k-1})$.

Remembering that everything of length $1$ and $2$ is automatically bad, we get a full count of the bads by summing, $k=3$ to $n$. If we feel like it, we can simplify, since our sums are finite geometric series.

Comment: I took it to be strings, so leading zeros were permitted, but the length was anything up to $16$.  But I see your reading as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve it with coupled recurrences.  Let $S(n)$ be the number of strings of length $n$ with none of $0,1,A$, $T(n)$ the number of strings with (any number of) only one of $0,1,A$, $U(n)$ with two, and $V(n)$ with three.  You want the sum from 3 to 16 of $V(n)$

The starting conditions are $S(1)=13, T(1)=3, U(1)=0, V(1)=0$ as there are thirteen one digit strings that are not $0,1,A$ and three that are.  Then $S(n)=13S(n-1)$ because you can get an $S$ string one longer by adding any digit except $0,1,A$.  What is the recurrence for $T(n)$.  You can get a $T$ string by starting with a $T$ string and adding (what?) or by starting with an $S$ string and adding (what)?  You can do these calculations easily in a spreadsheet.